# SQL Error code 1630 for SUM function in mysql

Tags: mysql

The code I am trying is as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(D.DriverFirstName,' ',D.DriverLastName)AS'Full Name',
SUM(T.EndOdometerKM-T.StartODometerKM) AS'Total KM Travelled'
FROM DRIVER AS D, TRIP AS T
WHERE D.DriverLicenceNum=T.DriverLicenceNum
GROUP BY T.DriverLicenceNum
HAVING SUM (T.EndOdometerKM-T.StartOdometerKM)>1000
ORDER BY SUM (T.EndOdometerKM-T.StartOdometerKM)ASC;
```

However, I receive this error message:

```
#1630 - FUNCTION dbname.SUM does not exist.
```

According to other posts, the problem is usually whitespace between the function and parentheses `(SUM (code))` as opposed to `(SUM(code))`, yet my problem still persists without the whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this  way should work

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(D.DriverFirstName,' ',D.DriverLastName) AS 'Full Name',
    SUM(T.EndOdometerKM-T.StartODometerKM) AS 'Total KM Travelled'
FROM DRIVER AS D, TRIP AS T
WHERE D.DriverLicenceNum=T.DriverLicenceNum
GROUP BY T.DriverLicenceNum
HAVING SUM(T.EndOdometerKM-T.StartOdometerKM) > 1000
ORDER BY SUM(T.EndOdometerKM-T.StartOdometerKM) ASC;
```

Comment: can you explain a bit as to why the error occurs in the query specified in the question ?

Comment: It seems to have been unnecessary whitespace in the two final lines of code. Also added spaces around > symbol and before ASC